# 'square' whose outline is all *'s and whose interior is filled with the character "."

Tags: java

I need to draw a square whose outline is all `*`'s and the interior is filled with the character `.` (dot).
There is also input which will determine the size of the square.
This is what I have so far.
I think I need a "if" statement but don't know how to implement this.
So far this bit of code will draw a square of `*` by BIO user input.

Thanks in advance :).

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        int stars = BIO.getInt();
        int a = 1;

        while (a <= stars)
        {
            int starsNumber = 1;

            while (starsNumber <= stars)
            {
                starsNumber = starsNumber + 1;
                System.out.print('*');
            }

            System.out.println();

            a = a +1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The names obfuscate what you're doing. It would probably be a lot easier for you to conceptualize by thinking about `a` as your "vertical coordinate" and `starsNumber` as your "horizontal coordinate." Then you can decide whether to print a `*` or a `.` using a check on the horizontal coordinate and vertical coordinate. You should figure the particular check out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will break this problem down into steps. Try figuring out the code yourself.

You have to print the following things:

- The top of the square. this will be a series of * with a length of `stars` e.g. `*****`
- `stars` lots of middle bits. This will be a * at the start, then a series of . with a length of `stars - 2`, then a * at the end e.g. `*...*`
- The bottom of the square. Exactly the same as the top.

---

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < stars ; i++) {
    System.out.print("*"); // top
}
System.out.println(); // new line
for (int j = 0 ; j < stars - 2 ; j++) {
    System.out.print("*"); // starting * of the middle
    for (int i = 0; i < stars - 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("."); // the dots for the middle
    }
    System.out.print("*"); // the star at the end of the middle lines
    System.out.println(); // new line for the next middle line
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < stars ; i++) {
    System.out.print("*"); // bottom
}
```

Comment: It's arguably much more concise to use just one doubly-nested loop as Ali AK has done and to decide whether to print a `*` or a `.` based on the values of `a` and `starsNumber` (which should probably be called `i` and `j` or `y` and `x`).

Comment: @hexaflexagonal yeah but I was trying to make this as intuitive as possible. You can post another answer if you want.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am getting it now. just had one of those moments were I was just blank. Literally didn't know where to start. Thanks. Did want to know if there is another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I used a two-dimensional array to store char values of the * and . of the square with a nested loop to generate the array and to print it out. When generating it, use an if-else statement to determine if you are generating the border of the square or not, choosing whether to put a * or . into this index of the array.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Square size: ");
int size = scanner.nextInt();

char[][] square = new char[size][size];                         //two-dimen array helps visualize square shape you want

for (int row=0; row<size; row++) {
    for (int col=0; col<size; col++) {
        if (row==0 || row == size-1 || col==0 || col==size-1) { //if border of square
            square[row][col] = '*';
        }
        else {                                                  //if inside square
            square[row][col] = '.';
        }
    }
}

for (char[] row : square) {
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (char col : row) {
        System.out.print(col);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your basic loop structure:

```
for (int row = 0; row < stars; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < stars; col++) {
        char c;
        if (CONDITION)
            c = '*';
        else
            c = '.';
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You should figure out `CONDITION` yourself. Think about what `x` and `y` need to be in the cases where you want to print a `*` instead of a `.`.